# Multiple row show in one row as sum in sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID |A    |B    
1   1     3   
1   412   2 
2   567   3   
2   567   1 
3   2     3 
3   5     4 
4   6     1    
4   8     2 
4   2     3
```

I want to get table:

```
ID |A    |B    
1   413   5
2   1134  4
3   7     7
4   16    6
```

Comment: This looks like a basic `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, you want to use a group by clause for aggregate functions. In this case, you are summing the values for A and B, and grouping them by ID. The syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(A), SUM(B)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Code-only answer is not so good and you should explain your code.